# Printf does not print the correct values after scanf (ex. 5 is printed as 6618624)

Tags: c, integer, output, printf, scanf

I wrote up a simple calculator that utilizes functions.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void operation_menu();
int getNumber(int,int);
int sum(int,int);
int diff(int,int);
int mult(int,int);
double quot(double,int);
int choice,num1,num2;

int main(){

    getNumber(num1,num2);
    operation_menu();

return 0;
    
}

int getNumber(int num1,int num2){

    printf("Welcome to Simple Calculator!\n");
    printf("Please input a number to begin:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("Great! Now input the second number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num2);

}
void operation_menu(){

    printf("Select an operation: \n");
    printf("1. Addition\n");
    printf("2. Subtraction\n");
    printf("3. Multiplication\n");
    printf("4. Division\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    switch(choice){
        case 1:
            printf("The sum of %d and %d is %d.", num1,num2,sum(num1, num2));
        break;
        case 2:
            printf("The difference of %d and %d is %d.", num1,num2,diff(num1, num2));
        break;
        case 3:
            printf("The product of %d and %d is %d.", num1,num2,mult(num1, num2));
        break;
        case 4:
            printf("The quotient of %d and %d is %.2lf.", num1,num2,quot(num1, num2));
        break;
        default:
            printf("Please try again.");
    }
}
    
    int sum(int num1,int num2){
        int answer;
        answer=num1+num2;
        return answer;
    }
    int diff(int num1,int num2){
        int answer;
        answer=num1-num2;
        return answer;
    }
    int mult(int num1,int num2){
        int answer;
        answer=num1*num2;
        return answer;
    }
    double quot(double num1,int num2){
        double answer;
        answer=num1/num2;
        return answer;
    }
```

The program worked correctly without breaking up my main() into several smaller functions, but after creating functions for each operation, input, and menu, I receive the wrong outputs. I figured this by printing num1 and num2 after using scanf and sure enough, I get the wrong outputs.

Comment: Don't use global variables unnecessarily like that. That is bad practice and is causing you confusion. `operation_menu` is using the global `num1` and `num2` whereas `getNumber` is scanning into local variables of the same name.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I noticed it as soon as you mentioned it. I have finished the program and it is running as intended. I'll try not to recklessly declare variables globally next time. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

The function `getNumber` changes its local variables (parameters) num1 and num2. After exiting the function these local variables are not alive. The global variables with the same names stay unchanged.

You need to pass the global variables by reference through pointers to them. For example

```
int getNumber(int *num1,int *num2){

    printf("Welcome to Simple Calculator!\n");
    printf("Please input a number to begin:\n");
    scanf("%d", num1);
    printf("Great! Now input the second number:\n");
    scanf("%d", num2);

}
```

The function is called like

```
getNumber( &num1, &num2 );
```

Pay attention to that there is no need to declare the variables num1, num2 and choice as global. You should declare them in the scope where they are used for example within the function `operation_menu`.

Also the both parameters of the function quot should have the type `int`. The function can be defined like

```
double quot( int num1,int num2){
    double answer;
    answer = ( double )num1/num2;
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I took everyone's advice and removed the global variables to declare them as local variables in main();. Also, upon looking at my code, I realized how messy it was so I scrapped it and wrote from scratch. I was able to finish and run the program with only around 2 errors in total (which I fixed, obviously). I apologize for asking basic questions but I am a beginner and I will continue looking into pointers. Thanks again!